# stylesheet works in brackets.io but not in chrome

Tags: css

I'm using brackets.io for web dev.
The page looks great in the live preview, but when I just open the file from chrome by "file:///localurl/index.html" The page is not styled at all.

I'm using this in the `<head>`:

```
<link href="css/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Using "inspect element" on the page opened in chrome, it seems no stylesheet is applied. (There is also a bootsrapt CSS included, which I omitted for simplicity, but that one is not applied in chrome as well)

What am I doing wrong? The stylesheets are in the `css` subfolders.

Comment: Replace **localurl** with *path* to your *index.html* file.

Comment: what do you mean *localurl*? I'm using *href" with a relative path to index.html, how should I specify this otherwise? It has to be a relative path, so when I put in on a remote server the relative paths are preserved, no?

Comment: this **localurl**: file:///localurl/index.html, in chrome address bar or simply open your index.html from your Finder/Explorer.

Comment: Solved it, should have used "./css/mystyles.css"

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, should have used `./css/mystyles.css` and not `css/mystyles.css`